# Problems customizing SendErrorFilter

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix

The [Spring Cloud Netflix documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html) states that the default forwarding path (/error) for SendErrorFilter can be changed by setting the error.path property. When I do this, I encounter the following error:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'basicErrorController' method 
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
to {[/proxyServiceError]}: There is already 'proxyServiceErrorController' bean method
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.acme.controller.ProxyServiceErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.acme.service.ProxyServiceBootstrap.main(ProxyServiceBootstrap.java:25)`

I modeled my error controller off of BasicErrorController. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProxyServiceErrorController` must implement `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController`. In spring boot, `BasicErrorController` will not be registered only if there is already an implementation of `ErrorController`.

[Spring boot source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L107)

Changing `error.path` will also affect `BasicErrorController`. `BasicErrorController` and your `ProxyServiceErrorController` are trying to register controllers on the same path - `/proxyServiceError` now.